# How to click a button using selenium - website

Tags: python, selenium, button, click

I'd like to open the http inside the code below and click on the graph button that show the candlestick.
This is because then I'd like to perfrom a screenshot and save the graph image of the title.
Could you help me?

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.plus500.it/Instruments/TSLA")


try:
    element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID, "ButtonLine"))
    element.click()

except:
    print('not found')
    driver.quit()
```

---

Comment: always print out your exception to see what is going wrong. do `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: I tried your advice.the result is "Message: element click intercepted: Element <a id="ButtonLine" onclick="changeSeriesType(this)" class="small button icon icon-stats-dots"></a> is not clickable at point (451, 624). Other element would receive the click: <p>...</p>
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)"

Comment: It means the button I want to click is not a button, is it? I don't understand why python says "Other element would receive the click"..Thank you for your support, I'm really new to this kind of language

Comment: SOLVED: added WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='button small cookie-button']"))).click() before click on ButtonLine in order to remove cookie policy. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error you were getting (but didn't appear as you wear using try...except) was :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID, "ButtonLine"))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Reason: You forgot a parenthesis

Fix:

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ButtonLine")))
```

Just tested it, it works fine.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your correction =)  But I had this kind of issue: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a id="ButtonLine" onclick="changeSeriesType(this)" class="small button icon icon-stats-dots"></a> is not clickable at point (451, 624). Other element would receive the click: <p>...</p> (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)" –  what does it refer to?

Comment: I saw in other topic that could be due to overlapping of coockie policy accept popup (in fact in the html page i found "<button type="button" class="button small cookie-button">Accetta</button>" in the position of my graph button. How can I accept or remove this popup?

Comment: SOLVED: added WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='button small cookie-button']"))).click() to remove policy coockie and then it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element and add after `.click()` like this:

```
find_element_by_xpath(xpath to element).click()
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please help me how to write the correct xpath?

Comment: Inspect element -> find the html code of the button -> right click -> copy -> Copy Full Xpath

Answer (score 0):

You should write this code as given below

```
xpath = browser.find_element_by_xpath('TYPE THE XPATH')
xpath.click()
```